# passing js object to mvc action in non ajax manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have working example of calling mvc action from javascript using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/Data/CreateMyData',
            data: JSON.stringify({ newData: myObj}),
            success: function () {
                alert("complete");
            }
        });
```

this is async call, I wonder how can call same url `/Data/CreateMyData` and pass `myObj` javascript object in tradiotional (non async) manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an `async: false` will  make the ajax call to be run synchronously

More details [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1948919.aspx?Difference%20between%20async%20false%20and%20async%20true%20in%20ajax) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)